# celery interval scheduled tasks are not executing after 24 hours

Tags: celery, django-celery, celery-task, celerybeat

I'm using django-celery-beat 
https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ to manage celery tasks in my django project.

---

Code Snippets:

> creating Interval time

```
def get_or_create_interval(interval_time):
    schedule,created = IntervalSchedule.objects.get_or_create( 
        every=interval_time,
        period=IntervalSchedule.HOURS,
    )
    return schedule
```

> creating a periodic task based on above interval time:

```
def set_periodic_task(project_name,task_name,project_id):
    interval = get_or_create_interval(25)
    PeriodicTask.objects.create(
        interval=interval,
        name='{0}-{1}'.format(project_name,project_id),
        task=task_name, 
        kwargs=json.dumps({'project_id': 35,
        }),
    )
```

---

I have created some periodic tasks with different interval times and noticed that tasks which are under 24 hours of interval times get executed only.

Highlighted tasks which don't executes.

[image]

Please let me know what could be the possible reasons for this behaviour.

`settings.py`

```
######## CELERY : CONFIG
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = "Asia/Kolkata"
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler'
### ThirdPartyTOols
```

```
→ pip3 list | grep "celery"
celery (4.2.1)
django-celery (3.2.2)
django-celery-beat (1.3.0)
```

Thank you.

Comment: What timezone and what version of celery are you using?

Comment: @2ps Updated the question.

Comment: @ArbazzHussain You're saying that a periodic task that's scheduled to run at an interval less than 24 hours works, but if the interval is longer than 24 hours it does not run?

Comment: Yes,Exactly @berto